# Better test reporting

Tags: testing

I'm looking for some help designing a better summary report. Right now we publish and send everything (execution% by modules, defects etc) in an excel and I was hoping if we could use that excel data to generate a live dashboard that would be accessible by a URL.

To add, the execution data comes from QTest and defects from JIRA. At this point we are even ok with filling data in excel manually and using that as a source for any reporting tool.

If a free tool is available, even more better.

Any leads, helps, feedback is appreciated.

Thanks,
MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need Microsoft's Power BI.  We've done a lot of reporting from JIRA using this free tool (Desktop).  If you need to share it with others "real time", you'll prefer the online experience for about $10/user/month.   But if you're looking to stay "free", you can simply share the Power BI file with your stakeholders.

I recommend AGAINST using the already built in JIRA APP.  It seems to want to pull back all your issues.   Instead, use a REST API Call like this:

```
https://domain/rest/api/2/search?jql=filter=22605&fields=id,key,summary,description
```

If you get more issues back than your Issue Search is configured for, the pagination can be a little tricky.   Also multiple values in a custom field need special handling.

Or if you're on premise and know your JIRA DB, direct SQL is an efficient way to go.

We use both mechanisms... (REST and SQL).  SQL let us add logic in the view of the data that JIRA itself doesn't report on easily.  (Parent-Child-subchild relationships and roll up of effort, story points, etc)

The best part of the Power BI solution is you should be able to integrate the data from JIRA and your test tool.  (We pull from JIRA and our time tracking system).

[image: REST API Through PowerBI]